# Merge row columns from a query in sql server

Tags: merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple query which returns the following rows :

Current rows:

```
Empl    ECode   DCode       LCode       Earn    Dedn    Liab
====    ====    =====       =====       ====    ====    ====
123     PerHr   Null        Null        13      0       0
123     Null    Union       Null        0       10      0
123     Null    Per         Null        0       20      0
123     Null    Null        MyHealth    0       0       5
123     Null    Null        401         0       0       10
123     Null    Null        Train       0       0       15
123     Null    Null        CAFTA       0       0       20
```

However, I needed to see the above rows as follows :

```
Empl    ECode   DCode   LCode       Earn    Dedn    Liab
====    ====    =====   =====       ====    ====    ====
123     PerHr   Union   MyHealth    13      10      5
123     Null    Per     401         0       20      10
123     Null    Null    Train       0       0       15
123     Null    Null    CAFTA       0       0       20
```

It's more like merging the succeeding rows into the preceding rows wherever there are Nulls encountered for `EarnCode`, `DednCode` & `LiabCode`. Actually what I wanted to see was to roll up everything to the preceding rows.

In Oracle we had this `LAST_VALUE` function which we could use, but in this case, I simply cannot figure out what to do with this.

In the example above, `ECode`'s sum value column is `Earn`, `DCode` is `Dedn`, and `LCode` is `Liab`; notice that whenever either of `ECode`, `DCode`, or `LCode` is not null, there is a corresponding value in `Earn`, `Dedn`, or the `Liab` columns.

By the way, we are using SQL Server 2008 R2 at work.

Hoping for your advice, thanks.

Comment: What exactly are the rules, when do you merge and when don't you?

Comment: I would also like to see your requirements regarding this.

Comment: Actually, the only requirement is to "compress" all the Codes to occupy a row if possible, along with it's summarized values.  In the above example, ECode PerHr is the first row, and both DCode & LCode have none; however, in the second row, DCode has a Union code, this Union code will move up, along with it's Dedn sum, to occupy the null DCode.  LCode MyHealth will move to occupy the vacant LCode on the very first row.  So basically, compress all codes to occupy preceding rows wherever there are nulls for ECode, DCode & LCode.

Comment: I tried using "group by", it doesn't work; it still separates the codes (Ecode, Dcode, LCode) into it's own separate rows.

Comment: I've done this before and the only thing to be done is to add an order to the source which is consistent and rank WHERE column IS NOT NULL and then rejoin on the rank.  It's going to be ugly, though.  Effectively your column values have little to do with the row they are in - i.e. they do not relate to a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the same technique as Tango_Guy does but without the temporary tables and with the sort made explicit.  Because the number of rows per Empl is <= the number of rows already in place, I didn't need to make a dummy table for the leftmost table, just filtered the base data to where there was a match amongst the 3 codes.  Also, I reviewed your discussion and the Earn and ECode move together.  In fact a non-zero Earn in a column without an ECode is effectively lost (this is a good case for a constraint - non-zero Earn is not allowed when ECode is NULL):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7bd04/3

```
CREATE TABLE data(ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
                  Empl VARCHAR(3), 
                  ECode VARCHAR(8), 
                  DCode VARCHAR(8), 
                  LCode VARCHAR(8),
                  Earn INT NOT NULL,
                  Dedn INT NOT NULL,
                  Liab INT NOT NULL ) ;

INSERT INTO data (Empl, ECode, DCode, LCode, Earn, Dedn, Liab)
VALUES ('123', 'PerHr', NULL, NULL, 13, 0, 0),
        ('123', NULL, 'Union', NULL, 0, 10, 0),
        ('123', NULL, 'Per', NULL, 0, 20, 0),
        ('123', NULL, NULL, 'MyHealth', 0, 0, 5),
        ('123', NULL, NULL, '401', 0, 0, 10),
        ('123', NULL, NULL, 'Train', 0, 0, 15),
        ('123', NULL, NULL, 'CAFTA', 0, 0, 20);

WITH basedata AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS OrigSort, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY Empl ORDER BY ID) AS EmplSort
    FROM data
),
E AS (
  SELECT Empl, ECode, Earn, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY Empl ORDER BY OrigSort) AS EmplSort
  FROM basedata
  WHERE ECode IS NOT NULL
),
D AS (
  SELECT Empl, DCode, Dedn, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY Empl ORDER BY OrigSort) AS EmplSort
  FROM basedata
  WHERE DCode IS NOT NULL
),
L AS (
  SELECT Empl, LCode, Liab, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY Empl ORDER BY OrigSort) AS EmplSort
  FROM basedata
  WHERE LCode IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT basedata.Empl, E.ECode, D.Dcode, L.LCode, E.Earn, D.Dedn, L.Liab
FROM basedata
LEFT JOIN E
    ON E.Empl = basedata.Empl AND E.EmplSort = basedata.EmplSort
LEFT JOIN D
    ON D.Empl = basedata.Empl AND D.EmplSort = basedata.EmplSort
LEFT JOIN L
    ON L.Empl = basedata.Empl AND L.EmplSort = basedata.EmplSort
WHERE E.ECode IS NOT NULL OR D.DCode IS NOT NULL OR L.LCode IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY basedata.Empl, basedata.EmplSort
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Just some minor tweaks to adapt it to our current stored procedure and got our payroll report to work.  Maybe someone else out there will find these codes as a basis when they encounter a similar situation.  Kudos to Cade and Tango_Guy for providing the algorithm !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you need but have you tried coalesc

```
SELECT Name, Class, Color, ProductNumber,
COALESCE(Class, Color, ProductNumber) AS FirstNotNull
FROM Production.Product ;
```

Comment: This is an example from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: Coalesce combines things horizontally (across columns) ... he wants to do this across rows.

Comment: Tango_Guy is correct;  this needs to be done across rows, by pushing up all the lower rows to occupy any null ECode, DCode, & LCode in the preceding rows, as the example illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but it is very kludgy.  If anyone has something better, that would be great.

However, an algorithm:

1)  Get rownumbers for each distinct list of values in the columns
2)  Join all columns based on rownumber

Example:

```
select Distinct ECode   into #Ecode     from source_table   order by rowid;
select Distinct DCode   into #Dcode     from source_table   order by rowid;
select Distinct LCode   into #Lcode     from source_table   order by rowid;
select Distinct Earn    into #Earn  from source_table   order by rowid;
select Distinct Dedn    into #Dedn  from source_table   order by rowid;
select Distinct Liab    into #Liab  from source_table   order by rowid;

select b.ECode, c.DCode, d.LCode, e.Earn, f.Dedn, g.Liab
from source_table   a -- Note:  a source for row numbers that will be >= the below
left outer join #Ecode b on a.rowid = b.rowid
left outer join #DCode c on a.rowid = c.rowid
left outer join #LCode d on a.rowid = d.rowid
left outer join #Earn  e on a.rowid = e.rowid
left outer join #Dedn  f on a.rowid = f.rowid
left outer join #Liab  g on a.rowid = g.rowid
where 
    b.ecode is not null or
    c.dcode is not null or
    d.lcode is not null or
    e.earn is not null or
    f.dedn is not null or
    g.liab is not null;
```

I didn't include Empl, since I don't know what role you want it to play.  If this is all true for a given Empl, then you could just add it, join on it, and carry it through.

I don't like this solution at all, so hopefully someone else will come up with something more elegant.

Best,
David

Comment: This is a good solution nonetheless;  I tailored your code in conjunction with Cade's improvised algorithm and placed it inside a stored procedure using a table variable.  It worked really well.  Thanks!